# How do I create an API access_token in SuiteCRM?

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

How do I create an API access_token in SuiteCRM?

Their [documentation](https://docs.suitecrm.com/developer/api/developer-setup-guide/json-api/#_before_you_start_calling_endpoints) has prerequisites of 1) Install composer, 2) creating private and public keys for Oauth2, and 3) optionally changing the Oauth encryption key. I have completed all three. I don't know what to do next. Their documentation for non-developers like me is difficult to follow.

Server: AWS Linux2, SuiteCRM 7.10.27, Apache, MySQL 5.7.*

Answer (score 0):

1. Install composer. `done`
2. creating private and public keys for Oauth2. `done`
3. optionally changing the Oauth encryption key. `done`
4. Go to Admin, then **OAuth2 Clients and Tokens**
5. Create **New Password Client** (remember the pass)
6. Profit, I am attaching a curl example to my localhost instance accommodate please

`curl example, change HOST, CLIENT_ID, USER and PASS`

```
 curl --request POST \
  --url http://localhost:8080/Api/access_token \
  --header 'accept: application/json' \
  --header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --data scope= \
  --data grant_type=password \
  --data client_id=113c04ed-075f-5b0a-35ea-5f8cc9c24399 \
  --data client_secret=YourSecPass \
  --data username=admin \
  --data password=otherSecPass
```

Good luck

Comment: Thanks the reply. The command works without error, but I don't see any tokens that have been created?